# sed and Applescript shell script - strip character string

Tags: sed, applescript

I'm trying to use sed in a shell script in Applescript to strip this string - ?print=1 - from this html link in the variable the_html, which is `<a href="http://myurl.com.html?print=1">my link</a>`

but this throws an error:

```
set new_html to do shell script "echo " & quoted form of the_html & " | sed s=?print=1= =g'"
```

Do I need to escape the "="?

**Edit:**

Works now. Applescript didn't like an = escaped with a `\`, but escaping the whole string works:

```
sed 's/?print=1//g'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
echo '<a href="http://myurl.com.html?print=1">my link</a>' | sed 's/?print=1/ /g'
```

Comments:

- Put the HTML in quotes or escape it property
- When using `sed`, you generally use slashes: 's/a/b/'

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You need to escape the characters that have a special meaning. Now there are the standard regular expression special characters, and the character that you are using as a delimiter. So if you use = as the delimiter, you'll need to escape it with \.

Usually / is used as the delimiter. The exception is when you might be searching for /, which yields some pretty crazy and hard to read expressions with all the escaping.  So if you're searching for /s, I'd suggest using a different character, but otherwise, stick to /.

To answer the immediate question, you might escape the =:

> sed '=print\=1= =g'

or use the standard slash, without escaping the =:

> sed '/print=1/ /g'

Answer (score 1):

This works on my Mac:

```
echo '<a href="http://myurl.com.html?print=1">my link</a>' | sed 's=?print\=1= =g'
```

So the answer is, yes, you do need to escape the `=` since it is used an expression delimiter.

Comment: Thanks, but I neglected to menntion that I am using the shell script in Applescript, and Applescript didn't like the \ to escape the =.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to escape `'='` if using another `sed` separator like `'/'` or `','`. But if you wish to get URL *parameters*:

With `'?'` prefix:

```
 echo '<a href="http://myurl.com.html?print=1">my link</a>' \
    | sed -e 's,.*\(?.*\)\".*,\1,'
```

Without the `'?'` :

```
echo '<a href="http://myurl.com.html?print=1">my link</a>' \
    | sed -e 's,.*?\(.*\)\".*,\1,'
```

The best is also to split parameters:

```
$ echo '<a href="http://myurl.com.html?print=1&convert=4">my link</a>' \
    | sed -e 's,.*?\(.*\)\".*,\1,' -e 's,&,\n,g'
print=1
convert=4
```

Have fun ! :)